# Handing error "index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0" within a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Sara',  'John', 'Christine'],

                   'email': ['sara@example.com', 'john@example.com', 'Christine@example.com'],
                   'Country': ['US', 'US', 'UK'],
                   'Age': [25, 18, 33],
                   'Grade': ['High', 'Medium', 'Low']})

df1
```

Gives:

```
    name       email                  Country   Age Grade
0   Sara      sara@example.com            US    25  High
1   John      john@example.com            US    18  Medium
2   Christine   Christine@example.com     UK    33  Low
```

What I am trying to do is searching within the df1 with certain criteria to find the country but I got this error returned from the function if values are not in the df1:

```
def getcon(name, Grade):
    con = df1.loc[(df1['name'] == name) & (df1['Grade'] == Grade), 'Country'].values[0]
```

If non existing name or grade passed to the function this will throw:

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I tried to return none if the `con is not true` but I did not work:

```
def getcon(name, Grade):
    con = df1.loc[(df1['name'] == name) & (df1['Grade'] == Grade), 'Country'].values[0]
    if con is True:
        return con
    else:
        return None
```

How can I avoid this error if non existing values passed to the `getcon` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
def getcon(name, Grade):
    con = df1.loc[(df1['name'] == name) & (df1['Grade'] == Grade), 'Country']

    return con.iloc[0] if len(con) else None
```